# How do I enable containerd?

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks, containerd

When I run `systemctl status containerd`, I get the following output:

```
● containerd.service - containerd container runtime
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/containerd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-08-31 19:22:36 UTC; 6 months 27 days ago
     Docs: https://containerd.io
 Main PID: 3881 (containerd)
    Tasks: 165
   Memory: 87.5M
   CGroup: /system.slice/containerd.service
```

**How can I  change the status to enabled and what are the possible consequences of doing so?**

Other facts:

- This is running Amazon Linux 2 on an EKS worker node.
- The `containerd` version is `containerd github.com/containerd/containerd 1.6.6 10c12954828e7c7c9b6e0ea9b0c02b01407d3ae1`.
- The `kubelet` version is `Kubernetes v1.22.12-eks-ba74326`.

Comment: Check `systemctl status containerd.socket`, I think containerd is a service/socket pair and the socket would be the one to enable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `sudo systemctl enable containerd.service`

it will create the necessary symlinks for the containerd.service to be started during the boot process.

And to verify `systemctl is-enabled containerd.service`